# hide listview on click

Tags: android, listview, onclick, hide

## Hide listview on click

hi all,
i want to hide a listview on a click of a button.
i have a mainactivity.in which there are 2 listviews.

and my mainactivity extends Activity which can't be used by implements keyword..
and for hiding listview your activity must extends listactivity. as in below code..

but android donot use multiple inheritance. so how it could be done?

```
    Use getListView().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); within your ListActivity.

    This is how it looks inside your code:

    public OnClickListener teamlisten = new OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(View v) {
          getListView().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
       }
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

Get list view by `findViewById(R.id.mylistiview)` and then use `mylistview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)`

Answer (score 0):

In order to access a listview , let there be two listviews in your activity xml like:

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  <ListView 
      android:id="@+id/listview1"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
  <ListView 
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:id="@+id/listview2"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_below="@+id/listview1"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Initialize the listviews in the onCreate as :

```
mListView1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview1);
mListView2 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview2)
```

To access the listview on button click (assuming there is a button in your layout)

```
mListView1.setVisibility(View.GONE); // or View.INVISIBLE
```